# Query and sum all with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to fetch all users `user_totaldocs` and `user_totalthings` and want to **sum** those variables.

How can it's possible? Here is user schema:

```
var user_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    local : {
        ...
        ...
        user_id          : String,
        user_totaldocs   : Number,
        user_totalthings     : Number
        ....

    }
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to add calculated fields to a result. There are some examples below using the `mongo` shell, but the syntax in Mongoose's [Aggregate() helper](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) is similar.

For example, to calculate sums (per user document) you can use the [`$add` expression](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) in a [`$project` stage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.user.aggregate(
    // Limit to relevant documents and potentially take advantage of an index
    { $match: {
        user_id: "foo"
    }},

    { $project: {
        user_id: 1,
        total: { $add: ["$user_totaldocs", "$user_totalthings"] }
    }}
)
```

To calculate totals across multiple documents you need to use a [`$group` stage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with a [`$sum` accumulator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), for example:

```
db.user.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        total:       { $sum: { $add: ["$user_totaldocs", "$user_totalthings"] } },
        totaldocs:   { $sum: "$user_totaldocs" },
        totalthings: { $sum: "$user_totalthings" }
    }}
)
```

You may want only the one `total` field; I've added in `totaldocs` and `totalthings` as examples of calculating multiple fields.

A group `_id` of `null` will combine values from all documents passed to the `$group` stage, but you can also use other criteria here (such as grouping by `user_id`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use aggregation framework provided by mongodb. For your case --

if you want to fetch sum of user_totaldocs and sum of user_totalthings across the collection (meaning for all users), do --

```
db.user_schemas.aggregate(
 [
  {
    $group : {
       user_id : null,
       user_totaldocs: { $sum: "$user_totaldocs"}, // for your case use local.user_totaldocs
       user_totalthings: { $sum: "$user_totalthings" }, // for your case use local.user_totalthings
       count: { $sum: 1 } // for no. of documents count
    }
  }
])
```

To sum user_totaldocs and user_totalthings for particular user in a collection(assuming there are multiple document for a user), this will return sum for each user, DO --

```
db.user_schemas.aggregate(
 [
  {
    $group : {
       user_id : "$user_id", 
       user_totaldocs: { $sum: "$user_totaldocs"}, // for your case use local.user_totaldocs
       user_totalthings: { $sum: "$user_totalthings" }, // for your case use local.user_totalthings
       count: { $sum: 1 } // for no. of documents count
    }
  }
])
```

No need to provide individual user id.

For more info read: 
1. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group
2. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/