# Use $group with find in mongodb node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I want to group by `user_id` from `order` collection where there are lots of entries but I want to fetch the top 5 users that have made more orders and sum the overall price of particular user.

For example, if I made 10 orders I want to fetch my id and sum of my all orders.
 I have used below code but its not working:

```
Order.find({$group : { user_id : "$user_id"}},function(error,fetchAllTopUsers){
    console.log('##################');
      console.log(fetchAllTopUsers);
    })
```

I have checked this example but they are not using find with `$group`. I am new in Node.js and MongoDB.

[Query and sum all with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557966/query-and-sum-all-with-mongoose)

**Sample documents**

```
{ user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c', totalprice : 100 },
{ user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c', totalprice : 59 },
{ user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c', totalprice : 26 },
{ user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c', totalprice : 533 },
{ user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c', totalprice : 544 },    
{ user_id : '57efb93fdc78c816a3a15c4a', totalprice : 250 },
{ user_id : '57efb93fdc78c816a3a15c4a', totalprice : 157 },
{ user_id : '57efb93fdc78c816a3a15c4a', totalprice : 149 },
{ user_id : '57efb93fdc78c816a3a15c4a', totalprice : 104 }
```

I'm expecting an output like below:

```
{
    user_id : '57c7f4312b3c9771219bd21c',
    finalTotal : 1262
},
{   
    user_id : '57efb93fdc78c816a3a15c4a'
    finalTotal : 660
}
```

Comment: ok, let me add table data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator is only available with the aggregation framework hence you need to run an aggregation pipeline that groups the documents by the `user_id` field and then sorts the documents by the aggregated `finalTotal` field using **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** and then get the top 5 documents using **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)**.

Follow this pipeline to get the needed result:

```
Order.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "finalTotal": { "$sum": "$totalprice" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "finalTotal": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 5 }
]).exec(function(error, fetchAllTopUsers){
    console.log('##################');
    console.log(fetchAllTopUsers);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i need to sum total price by user_id. like pritesh make 100 orders and overall price is 15000, Chridam make 3 orders and overall price is 5000 like that

Comment: Above answer is working but below is not working. see my comment one more time. i have edited with example

Comment: Added my data as well

Comment: @PriteshMahajan Thanks, much more clearer. I've updated my answer, that should address your requirements.

Comment: this answer is working fine but now i am facing a issue that is for string. in db "totalprice" is string type. so when i get result "finalTotal" with showing always 0. not sum my values.

Comment: You need to first update your collection by converting the fields with the string values to numeric values. Consider the answers in these question [MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field), [MongoDB convert string type to float type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942844/mongodb-convert-string-type-to-float-type/) and [how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

We can use like this

```html
db.getCollection('form_a').aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Status",
            "counter": { "$sum": 1 }
            
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: form_a is the collection name